# Replace JBossWS with CXF on JBoss 6.1 EAP

Tags: java, jboss, cxf

I can't find any tutorial on doing this, is it possible?

I'm using a fresh install of JBoss 6.1 EAP, but I think it's using the JbossWS stack when I need it to use CXF.

Comment: Why do you think it is using the wrong implementation?

Comment: because when I deploy my application, it tries to create web services out of all my web service client jars.

Comment: Unless your webservice is a JAX-RPC one, all other JAX-WS webservice will automatically use JBossWS-CXF. Only JAX-RPC uses JBossWS-Native stack.